# setting UITableView SelectedCell Accessory type to checkmark

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am setting `UITableview` selected cell style to chek mark but problem is that it shows check when a cell is selected but when we select new cell another cell aslo gets check marked with first also. I want that only one check mark to be shown of the selected cell

```
   UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];


} 
else {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` before return cell;

```
    if (self.selectedIndexPath != nil && self.selectedIndexPath.row == indexPath.row
                && self.selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

And this code to your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.selectedIndexPath != nil) {
        // Uncheck previously selected cell
        UITableViewCell *prevSelectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
        [prevSelectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```